# Unable to correctly parse a date from Excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, date, parsing, datetime

I'm importing Excel rows and one of the columns is a Date field. There are two scenarios in which I receive the date.

The **first** is I receive the date correctly as a Double. For this scenario a simple `DateTime.FromOADate(parsedDouble)` works.

The **second** scenario is for whatever reason, the client has not properly formatted the cell or the value in the cell has not been recognised correctly although is a valid date. For example the date will be `1/12/2016` which in the UK format is `1st December 2016`. Excel also passes format information for the cell, so in this case it passes through the cell format "*`dd/mm/yyyy`*". This is the correct day/month/year format in excel however I need to be able to parse it in c# and I'm unable to because lower case `mm` is **minutes** and not **months**.

So the following won't work.

```
var x = DateTime.ParseExact("12/12/2016", "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It will output *`12/01/2016 00:12:00`*

I've had a look around and can't seem to find anyone else having the same issue and I'm not quite sure how to deal with this.

An obvious (undesirable) solution would be to hack it and map the excel format of *`dd/mm/yyyy`* to *`dd/MM/yyyy`*.

Comment: I dont think you have much choice but to hack the date to pad in the zeros

Comment: Please explain why using the correct format of "dd/MM/yyyy" is undesirable.

Comment: Pad in zeros? I don't understand, why would I pad in zeros to a date. 
It's undesirable because these excel sheets are passed over from various countries and there is a high probability the format would for e.g. be in the american date format of MM/dd/yyyy - there has to be a more elegant way of dealing with this surely?

Comment: I copied your code like a fool and of course it said bad format.. sigh

Comment: It is actually valid code. As I've put in there, it will output 12/01/2016 00:12:00.. So it's taken the middle values as the minutes, and the first part and last part (day/year) correctly.

Comment: I just had an aha moment, how many possible different date formats do you have? UK and American?

Comment: Usually, when a column of dates in Excel is a mix of real dates and text-strings, the problem is with the input to Excel (eg a csv file with a format that does not match the regional settings for the target computer). If that is the case, then it is likely that the dates you are seeing as `real dates` has been parsed incorrectly by Excel.  That being the case, you are going to have to correct both the `real dates` and the `text dates`.  Or you could have your client import the data properly (or you could ask for the source file instead of the Excel file.

Comment: Would it feel less "hacky" if you fully interpreted the VBA `Range.NumberFormat`?  Like using Regex to parse whether "mm" means months or minutes based on the rules in Excel?  "mm" only means minutes in excel when it is preceded by "hh[:]"

Comment: I'm looking at a different solution, each time we are given the excel sheet data to import. It is coming from an Organisation which we know what timezone they belong to etc. From that I'm going to enforce the format. So for example, orgs in the UK would be sending it in MM/dd/yyyy and the UK orgs will be dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: I wish I could do that with my clients! *jealous*